# log error and warning info in iphone

Tags: iphone, warnings

I need to get the error, warning log when the iphone application is running and want to save it as a file in the database. i am using phpmysql as backend. is there any way to get this.?\

Help needed

Thanks,
Shibin

Comment: Please clarify 'phpmysql' - do you actually mean 'sqlite' on the iPhone or do you want to communicate the error information across the network to a PHP+MySQL web application?

Comment: Yes i want the log in my PHP+MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is probably beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow question. Issues you face are:

- How are you going to cache error information on the phone when there is no network available?
- When and how often are you going to communicate with the server?
- What protocol are you going to use between the phone and the PHP app?
- What sort of authentication are you going to use? You don't want anyone to be able to dump info into your database.
- How are you going to implement the PHP app?

Good luck!

Comment: 1) My iPhone is always connected to the internet using its wifi connectivity

2) Most probably when an error occurs, i am not sure how it can be done. Need to implement the TRY-CATCH logic

3) HTTP, mine is not that a secure connection so dont care about the SSL


Can you help me now???